# Negative Number preg_match_all

Tags: preg-match-all

Hi All im One function to convert ltr css to rtl but not work correct by any format my function is

```
public function rtlMargin($string)
{
    $string = trim($string);
    if (preg_match_all('~(-[0-9]+(px|%)?)~i', $string, $matches)) {
        $c = count($matches['1']);
        $p = $matches['1'];
        if ($c == 4)
            $order = implode(' ', array(
                $p['0'],
                $p['3'],
                $p['2'],
                $p['1']));
        else
            if ($c == 3)
                $order = implode(' ', array(
                    $p['0'],
                    0,
                    $p['2'],
                    $p['1']));
            else
            if ($c == 2)
                $order = implode(' ', array(
                    $p['0'],
                    0,
                    0,
                    $p['1']));
            else
            if ($c == 2)
                $order = implode(' ', array(
                    $p['0'],
                    0,
                    0,
                    $p['1']));
            else                
                $order = implode(' ', $p);

        if (preg_match('/auto/',$string)) {
            return 'margin: ' . $order . ' auto;' . '<br />';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'margin: ' . $order . ';' . '<br />';
        }            
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Code Test Function Is
    $res .= $MyConverter->rtlMargin("margin:1px 2px 3px 4px");

Output is
margin:1px 4px 3px 2px;

But

```
$res .= $MyConverter->rtlMargin("margin:1-px 2px 3-px 4px");
```

Output is Empty Bug For

```
if (preg_match_all('~(-[0-9]+(px|%)?)~i', $string, $matches))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the regular expression matches only sizes with minus, eg: -10px or -30%, you need to make the "-" optional putting the "?" (question mark) after, on the same way that the "px" or "%" are optionals: `(px|%)?`:

```
Your regexp:    '~(-[0-9]+(px|%)?)~i'
Correct regexp: '~(-?[0-9]+(px|%)?)~i'
```

PS: Note that `3-px` is not a valid negative margin, the correct syntax is `-3px`. Anyways, if you still would like to match 3-px you can use this regexp: `'~(-?[0-9]+-?(px|%)?)~i'`

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php